# Python Function to fill nan values based on another column

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a dataset like this

```
Ticket    Cabin
123       Nan
162       B14
123       C12
122       D13
162       Nan
122       Nan
```

So I want to fill Nan values based on Ticket values such as the result is

```
Ticket    Cabin
123       C12
162       B14
123       C12
122       D13
162       B14
122       D13
```

Is there any function or way we could do this?

Comment: What do you want to fill those 'Nan' values with? Is this a file you are reading? Do you want a file as output? Please expando your question.

Comment: what he want : take a copy of cabin, remove Nans, and use it to replace Nan's in the original Cabin column. I guess cyclically if there are more Nans than values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping of tickets to non-null Cabin values, then use this to backfill other rows:

```
df['Cabin_Filled'] = df['Ticket'].map(df.groupby('Ticket')['Cabin'].first())
df

   Ticket Cabin Cabin_Filled
0     123   NaN          C12
1     162   B14          B14
2     123   C12          C12
3     122   D13          D13
4     162   NaN          B14
5     122   NaN          D13
```